# How to compute average precision(AP) for multi label image classification?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, multilabel, model-evaluation

In multi label image classification task like that in Pascal VOC 2012, AP and mAP are used to evaluate the performance. My question is:

To compute the **Average Precision**, **how many labels and the corresponding confidence scores**(maybe a output vector of `softmax`) should I give to a **single** image?

Should I give the scores of all `C` classes(suppose I have `C` classes) or just `top-k`(e.g. `k=5`) classes?

Comment: In my implementation, all c predictions(c classes) or top-k predictions are both OK.